# Getting the error "parameter is not valid" for imagePath

Tags: c#, parameters

After running my code and accessing the user form I try to delete/update a current user or add a new user but the code stops running and I get the error:

> "parameter not the valid for my imagePath"

```cs
private void dataGridViewUsers_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Find the Row Index of the Row Clicked on Users Data Frid View
    int RowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    textBoxUserId.Text = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    textBoxUsername.Text = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBoxEmail.Text = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBoxPassword.Text = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    textBoxFullName.Text = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    textBoxContact.Text = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    textBoxAddress.Text = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    imageName = dataGridViewUsers.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

    //Update the Value of Global Variable rowHeaderImage
    rowHeaderImage = imageName;

    //Display the Image of SElected User
    //Get the Image path
    string paths = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, (Application.StartupPath.Length - 10));

    if (imageName != "no-image.jpg")
    {
        //Path to Destination Folder
        string imagePath = paths + "\\images\\" + imageName;
        //Diplay in Picture Box
        pictureBoxProfilePicture.Image = new Bitmap(imagePath);
    }
    else
    {
        //Path to Destination Folder
        string imagePath = paths + "\\images\\no-image.jpg";
        //Diplay in Picture Box
        pictureBoxProfilePicture.Image = new Bitmap(imagePath);
    }
}
```

I added an image showing the error location in my code

[image: image1]

Comment: debug and see what value you are getting for `imagePath`

Comment: @viveknuna i am getting this value D:\blood bank\Charbel Kinj Chaanine Blood Bank\Charbel Kinj Chaanine Blood Bank\images\no-image.jpg

Comment: Is file present on path?

Comment: I suggest you to use Path.Combine instead of adding the strings

Comment: @viveknuna yes the file is present on path 
sorry how can i use the path? i am new to this

Comment: Path.Combine(path1, path2);

Comment: @viveknuna i noticed now that the error is in the bitmap parameter
pictureBoxProfilePicture.Image = new Bitmap(imagePath);

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: when adding a new user or updating a user  im getting error: Empty file name is not legal.
Parameter name: sourceFileName
for this line of code : File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);

when using the clear function clear or deleting a user im getting the error : Parameter is not valid.
in this line of code: pictureBoxProfilePicture.Image = new Bitmap(imagePath);

if you have teamviewer and can help kindly send me an email : cc99blogger@gmail.com

Comment: Show the relevant code and line in which you are getting the error

Comment: @viveknuna you can find the whole user.cs code here
https://pastebin.com/WDzZaGhf

and thanks for your precious time